# Opening activity inside a navgraph with a deeplink causing a crash

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-deep-link

I have an activity inside an navgraph, directly i am able to navigate to it by below code

```
Navigation.findNavController(requireView())?.navigate(R.id.sampleActivity)
```

Please find the navgraph below

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/appFirstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/appFirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.deeplinkpoc.AppFirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_app_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_app_first" >
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/sampleActivity"
        android:name="com.example.deeplinkpoc.SampleActivity"
        android:label="activity_sample"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_sample">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink2"
            app:uri="https://www.abcdxyz.com/test" />
    </activity>
     </navigation>
```

**But if i try to navigate to it using deeplink its crashing**

```
Process: com.example.deeplinkpoc, PID: 12805
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deeplinkpoc/com.example.deeplinkpoc.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:271)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:1986)
    at androidx.navigation.ActivityNavigator.navigate(ActivityNavigator.java:200)
    at androidx.navigation.ActivityNavigator.navigate(ActivityNavigator.java:44)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1057)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.handleDeepLink(NavController.java:732)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:633)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:590)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:555)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:537)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
```

**UPDATE**
*please find navhost activity xml*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/home_nav_graph"
    /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i open an activity inside a navgraph with deeplink ?

Comment: Can you try adding latest `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'` dependency

Comment: added that dependency still not working

Comment: try changing "android:name="com.example.deeplinkpoc.SampleActivity"" to "class="com.example.deeplinkpoc.SampleActivity""

Comment: its inside nav-graph "class" attribute is not there

Comment: can you please paste the code from your navHostFragment (xml file). Maybe this could help us further.
(The error Log shows: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0
 )

Comment: hi Alex, updated the question with navhost xml, normal navigation to that activity is working fine. deeplink has the issue

Comment: Did you define any animations? please post your home_nav_graph as well

Comment: Did you add this in **manifest** `<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />`[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174934674), this is a known issue with Navigation 2.3.2, already marked as fixed for the upcoming Navigation 2.3.3 release.

However:

> note that it is **never** the right approach to attach a `<deeplink>` to an `<activity>` destination as that will never give you the right behavior when using an [implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) on another app's task (where the system back should immediately take the user back to the app that triggered your deep link). Instead, you should attach your deep link directly to your second activity (either by manually writing the appropriate `<intent-filter>` or by adding the `<deeplink>` to the start destination of a nav host in that second activity).

So really, you should move your `<deeplink>` off of your activity destination, which will both fix your crash (on every version of Navigation) and actually give you the correct behavior. Any validation you need to do needs to be done on the actual correct activity.

Comment: if i use sampleActivity to open deeplink directly, My UP(top left button) navigation will not take him to previous screen. For UP navigation i want to keep all activities in backstack so i am opening one common activity and navigating to target activity.

Comment: That just means either 1) you're not calling `super.onSupportNavigateUp()` like [the docs say](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar) or you haven't [declared a parent activity](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action#declare-parent).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these steps are followed:

1. `NavGraph` is added to `Application` class in `AndroidManifesto.xml`.
2. Add an `ACTION_VIEW` to the `DeepLink`.

If nothing else works, then the following solution will definitely work:

1. Add `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifesto` for `sampleActivity`.
2. Add an `implicit intent` to this `sampleActivity` tag, with `ACTION_VIEW`.
3. Collect this `implicit intent` in the `sampleActivity`'s `onCreate` lifecycle event.

You do not have to rely on `Navigation Component` to navigate to `simpleActivity` from the `deepLink`. You can register the deeplink yourself through `implicit intent` and it will just work fine.

What `NavigationComponent` does is it detects the `DeepLinks` present in the `Graph` and adds them to the `AndroidManifesto`. Your problem could originate from the fact that the `activity` you want to reach, i.e. `sampleActivity` lives in a `nestedGraph`. In this case, the `deepLink` would not be created. However, the `destionationId` of the `sampleActivity` will still be known to the `NavController`. Hence explaining why you are able to reach to `sampleActivity` from `destinationId` but not from `deepLink`.

To make your application aware of `sampleActivity` `deepLink`, you would have to propagate this `deepLink` setup to the `parentGraph`. Simply initialize the following `deepLink` in the `parentGraph`.

```
 <activity
        android:id="@+id/sampleActivity"
        android:name="com.example.deeplinkpoc.SampleActivity"
        android:label="activity_sample"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_sample">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink2"
            app:uri="https://www.abcdxyz.com/test" />
```

Comment: Hi, i don't want to open deeplink activity directly by mentioning in manifest xml. My main activity will receive the deeplink and after some validations it will send it through navgraph. Problem is if i am able to open the activity based on navgraph id, why can't i open same thing with deeplink.